# How to create another user admin to access admin directory centos6

Tags: centos

i can add new user but i can't access another user directory

$ adduser adminweb

$ passwd adminweb

$ chmod -aG adminweb admin

how  i can access directory such as /home/admin/public_html without permission denied, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the “adminweb” user to the “admin” group with usermod.

Next, you need to make sure that all the files in the “admin” user’s public_html directory are group owned by “admin”, have g+rw permission, and that the directory itself (and any subdirectories) have g+rwx permissions.

Don’t use chmod 777.

Answer (score -1):

you can try changing the directory's permissions.

`$ sudo chmod -R 777 /home/admin/public_html`

this makes the directory accessible to any user on the machine or, if you have set up networking, anyone on the network.